# #Name? error populating text control

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a text control to which I'd like to assign a value from a table returned by the following sql:

```
 SELECT tblProjMgrInfo.ProjMgrID AS MyProjMgrID
 FROM tblProjMgrInfo
 WHERE (((tblProjMgrInfo.PrjMgrWindowID)=GetLogonName()))
```

The GetLogonName function returns the windows login username.

The text box's control source is set as `=[qry_getPrjMgrID]![MyProjMgrID]` (w/o the quotes)

When I run the query object I get correct result.

When I run the form the control shows #Name?

Access 2010 - all with latest patches as of today
Windows 7 also with latest patches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DLookup` to fetch the field value from your saved query.

Set the Control Source property of your text box to this:

```vb
=DLookup("[MyProjMgrID]", "qry_getPrjMgrID")
```

Comment: Not sure if I can piggy back on to my own Q - on the same subj. If not please let me know and I'll repost.
continuing with the same issue - I created another control (bound to the query) and used a similar dlookup from another query.
When I open the form I see a flashing #Error and "calculating" in the status bar. The query works fine when I execute it - it prompts me for input - and displays correct result.

Comment: If the query requires the user to supply a parameter value, you can't use that query with `DLookup`.  If you need more on this, please show us the details of what you have as a new question.